# Margin/Padding bumping div when show/hide

Tags: css

I have a div that contains a couple of radio buttons. These show/hide a textbox.

```
<p>Some text</p>
<div>
    <div>
        <input id="show" name="radioGroup" type="radio" value="1" /><label for="show">Show</label> - 
        <input id="hide" name="radioGroup" type="radio" value="0" /><label for="hide">Hide</label>
    </div>
    <div class="myTextBox">
         <input type='text'>   
    </div>
</div>

<p>Some text</p>​
```

When I show/hide the `.myTextBox` then the text bumps a couple of pixels. This is due to the padding & margin on the textbox.

Without removing these settings (padding/margin) is there a way to eliminate the CSS bump?

See example on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nTJZN/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nTJZN/2/).

What I am doing is basically instead of `show()` and `hide()` I'm altering the `visibility` property.

```
function ShowHideTextbox()
{
    if($("#show").is(":checked"))
        $(".myTextBox").css('visibility','visible');
    else
        $(".myTextBox").css('visibility','hidden');   
}
```

​

Answer (score 1):

This is because your input box is taller than the text, which causes the line to grow when the input box is shown. By inspecting the element, I determined the line was 28px high when the input box was visible, so applying a line-height of 28px fixes the problem, like so:

```
div
{
 display: inline-block;   
 line-height: 28px;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/X4X3U/

Comment: If the user changes the font/font-size, this would have to be fixed again. It's a temporary solution.